# Golang generating a 32 byte key

Tags: go

I am using this library for sessions.

https://github.com/codegangsta/martini-contrib/tree/master/sessions

It says that:

*It is recommended to use an authentication key with 32 or 64 bytes. The encryption key, if set, must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes to select AES-128, AES-192, or AES-256 modes.*

How do I generate a 64 byte key, is it as straightforward as `[]byte"64characterslongstring"`, I thought it is not always so straight forward?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To generate a slice of 64 random bytes:

```
package main

import "crypto/rand"

func main() {
    key := make([]byte, 64)

    _, err := rand.Read(key)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```

Demo [here](http://play.golang.org/p/ZgvycIYxqt).

Comment: How do I get it into string format so I can save it in an environment variable?

Comment: @lee Base64 encoding of the random bytes should do it (https://gobyexample.com/base64-encoding)

Comment: @lee Updated the demo. Check it there.

Comment: If I save the base64 value in an environment variable, can I cast it straight to a byte slice or do I need to first decode it?